# Execute system command with Rake outside Bundle scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, bundler

Let say I have this Rake task:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :dump do.
    desc 'Backup database dump to s3'
    task :backup => :environment do 
      cmd = ['backup', 'perform',  '-t project_backup',  "-c #{Rails.root.join 'lib', 'backup', 'config.rb'}"] 
      system(*cmd)                      # ...I've tried `` & exec() sa well, same thing
    end
  end
end
```

Backup gem is stand alone ruby gem application which dependencies needs to be isolated from application bundler. In other words it cannot be part of `Gemfile`. This gem is simply installed over `gem install backup`

When I run `backup` command over bash console, it successfully run:

```
$ backup perform -t validations_backup -c /home/equivalent/my_project/lib/backup/config.rb
```

When I execute `rake db:dump:backup` I will get

```
backup is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

...which is the same thing when I run backup command with `bundle exec` from bash

```
$ bundle exec backup perform -t validations_backup -c /home/equivalent/my_project/lib/backup/config.rb
```

...meaning that the `backup` command is executed over bundler when run as part of rake task.

**my question:** How can I run `rake db:dump:backup` outsite the bundle scope, meaning that `backup` command won`t be executed over bundler?

Thank you

Comment: ...btw it successfully works as a remote  capistrano task as well

Comment: nope, not by Rake I'm still using Capistrano to do this. Posting answer with Capistrano example

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem [here](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup/issues/535):

```rb
namespace :db do
  namespace :dump do
    desc 'Backup database dump to s3'
    task :backup do
      Bundler.with_clean_env do
        sh "backup perform -t project_backup -c #{Rails.root.join 'lib', 'backup', 'config.rb'}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The key here is to enclose the code that must not run under bundler's environment in a block like this:

```rb
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  # Code that needs to run without the bundler environment loaded
end
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough - this issue has been KILLING me tonight!!  You superstar!

Comment: Thanks, can I elect you as my new god?

Comment: Also applies if you are trying to run this by invoking a shell within an app.  You may get "command not found" and  "rubygems_integration" and "cannot find executable" (adding to help searchers find this).  Just wrap calling your shell within this "Bundler.with_clean_env do" block and it works.  Thanks So Very Much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Capistrano solution I was mentioning for those who need it  while we figure out how to fix Rake.

```
class BackupDatabaseCmd
  def self.cmd
    # some logic to calculate :
    'RAILS_ENV=production backup perform -t name_of_backup_task -c  /home/deploy/apps/my_project/current/lib/backup/config.rb'
    # in the configuration file I'm loading `config/database.yml`
    # and passing them to backup gem configuration
  end
end

namespace :backup do
  namespace :database do
    task :to_s3 do
      on roles(:web) do
        within release_path do
          with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
            execute(BackupDatabaseCmd.cmd)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# cap production backup:database:to_s3
```